# How to send PHP variable through href

Tags: php, html

This is my fetch.php file which works currently but I can't seem to connect my php hyperlink to the gene.php file.

I'm thinking about how I can separate the html from the php to follow other suggestions but struggling on how to do this.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 $output .= '
 <tr>
<td><a href="gene.php?id=' . $row['mRNA'] . '">'.$row["mRNA"].'</a></td>
<td><a href="gene.php?id=' . $row['mRNA'] . '">'.$row["Gene"].'</a></td>
<td>'.$row["Subtype"].'</td>
</tr>
';
  }
echo $output;
}
?>
```

If possible, I'm hoping I could pass the new gene.php?id variable back as a query on my gene.php page.

```
   <?php
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
   $id[0] = $_REQUEST['id'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM genenames WHERE mRNA=".$id."";
```

Comment: Yes?  `$id[0] = $_REQUEST['id'];` should probably just be `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` You need to read up on SQL injection. You can never trust user input.

Comment: And what exactly is the result of your current code? How does it differ from what you want?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1):

try using PDO, it's prettier when it comes to prepared statements.

```
<?php

// userinput is evil
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
// or
$id = filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// abort here, if $id is not valid

// connection config
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 3306;
$name = 'db-name';
$username = 'db-username';
$password = 'db-password';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
];

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$name;

$result = [];
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM genenames WHERE mRNA=:id";

    $params = [
        'id' => $id
    ];

    $mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    if($statement->execute($params))
    {
        $statement->setFetchMode($mode);
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage());
}


$output = '<table>';

// print your rows
foreach($result as $row) {

    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td><a href="gene.php?id=' . $row['mRNA'] . '">'.$row["mRNA"].'</a></td>
            <td><a href="gene.php?id=' . $row['mRNA'] . '">'.$row["Gene"].'</a></td>
            <td>'.$row["Subtype"].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}

$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code 
and check to work for you

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
 $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
 echo $id;//check for id it print or not
 $query = "SELECT * FROM genenames WHERE mRNA=".$id."";
```

or something like that as you did via index of id

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
 $id[0] = $_REQUEST['id'];
 echo $id[0];//check for id it print or not
 $query = "SELECT * FROM genenames WHERE mRNA=".$id[0]."";
```

But it is a sql injection problem,you are allowing others to pass via URL I suggest you to read about SQL injection.Use form to post the data or another way to send that close to prevent you from sql injection.